# CSS special columns

Tags: html, css

I need to create columns with CSS. I have a lot of data (names) and I need to have it in 3 columns (like in Word). I am not thinking of a table, I need the content of the columns to be dynamic.
Like this

```
John Smith |  John Smith |  John Smith
John Smith |  John Smith |  John Smith
John Smith |  John Smith |  John Smith
John Smith |  John Smith |
```

If I add new "John", all columns will rearange like this

```
Joe Smith  |  John Smith |  John Smith
John Smith |  John Smith |  John Smith
John Smith |  John Smith |  John Smith
John Smith |  John Smith |  John Smith
```

Is this possible by CSS?
Thank you.

Comment: check this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: @moped thank you, but "Note: Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.". Is there some kind of workaround for IE?

Comment: IE9 is not even supported by Microsoft, you can either display "upgrade message" or stick to a div columns with 33% width and you'll need to split array of names into 3 parts ..

Comment: please clarify how you obtain these data (can you manipulate with the output with PHP for example?) and in what direction should your data move (When new name is added, will it move last name from first column to first position of second column etc. OR will it move first name of first column to first position in second column?)

Comment: Try flexbox. I think it will solve your problem efficiently.

Comment: Yes, the data is processed by PHP with Nette. And it should move this direction - 'move last name from first column to first position of second column'

Comment: @user3129342 If you have special requirements, such as needing to support IE9, you should say so in the question. That way, the answers will be much better suited to your issue. Also, it's not at all clear from the example where the new name is inserted in the list. At the top, at the bottom, is the list kept sorted etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="names">
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
    <div>John Smith</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.names {

     -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; 
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: solid; 
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid; 
    column-rule-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>John</td> 
    <!--td>Your name here</td-->
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you :)